# Multiple dto for the same entity in list and detail pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, viewmodel, dto

I'm developing a site using Asp net MVC and EF.
I chose to not bring domain objects to the view layer, so I create DTO to do that (and Automapper to map domain to dto objects)

I have a page **Course/List** that list all courses.
So I create a **CourseDTO**

```
public class CourseDTO{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
  public List<ArgumentsDTO> Arguments {get;set;} //NOTE THIS
}

public class CourseListViewModel{
  public List<CourseDTO> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

In the **Course/Detail/123** page I want to show also the teachers of the course.

What is the best solution?
Reuse the CourseDTO and bring the list of Teachers to the view using a separate list

```
public class CourseDetailViewModel{
  public CourseDTO Course { get; set; }
  public List<TeacherDTO> Teachers {get;set;} //NOTE THIS
}
```

or create a CourseDetailDTO that contain also the list of Teachers?

```
public class CourseDetailDTO{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }
  public List<ArgumentsDTO> Arguments {get;set;} 
  public List<TeacherDTO> Teachers {get;set;} //NOTE THIS
}
```

In this last case I will have two DTO for the same domain object..

Answer (score 0):

The question here is whether in the `Detail` view you will need all the properties of `CourseDTO`. If so then the first solution seems nice and reuse the `CourseDTO` view model. If on the other hand in the Detail view you have some specific requirements in terms of formatting some of the properties of this course the second approach is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use multiple DTOs for the same Entity... but would be good if someone could confirm this is indeed not bad practice.

I like having separate DTOs because that means less data may have to be retrieved hence an increase in performance. No point in supplying data that is not needed.